# Radix-Sort Implementation for Dictionary/KeyValuePair Collection

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, key-value, radix-sort

I'm looking for a fast and efficient Radix-Sort Implementation for Dictionary/KeyValuePair Collection if possible in C# (but not mandatory). The key is an Integer between 1 000 000 and 9 999 999 999. The number of values are varying between 5 to several thousand.
At the moment I'm using LINQ-OrderBy, which is I think QuickSort. For me performance is really important and I would like to test whether a Radix-Sort would be faster.
I found only Array implementations. Of course I could try it by myself but because I'm new to this topic I believe it wouldn't be the fastest and most efficient algorithm. ;-)
Thank you.

Rene

Comment: Use one of the array implementations you found and keep two arrays: one with the keys and one with the values. Modify the implementation so it sorts the keys array, and whenever it makes a modification, it makes the same modification to the values array.

Comment: Yes, I had already a similar idea, also with two lists. But I think managing two lists destroys the advantage of the faster radix sort, because the difference isn't big enough to QuickSort.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested your code to determine that the LINQ-based sort is the bottleneck in your program? LINQ's sort is pretty darned quick. For example, the code below times the sorting of a dictionary that contains from 1,000 to 10,000 items. The average, over 1,000 runs, is on the order of 3.5 milliseconds.

```
static void DoIt()
{
    int NumberOfTests = 1000;

    Random rnd = new Random();

    TimeSpan totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTests; ++i)
    {
        // fill the dictionary
        int DictionarySize = rnd.Next(1000, 10000);
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        while (dict.Count < DictionarySize)
        {
            int key = rnd.Next(1000000, 9999999);
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                dict.Add(key, "x");
            }
        }
        // Okay, sort
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var sorted = (from kvp in dict
                        orderby kvp.Key
                        select kvp).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
        totalTime += sw.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("{0:N0} items in {1:N6} ms", dict.Count, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Total time = {0:N6} ms", totalTime.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("Average time = {0:N6} ms", totalTime.TotalMilliseconds / NumberOfTests);
```

Note that the reported average includes the JIT time (the first time through the loop, which takes approximately 35 ms).

Whereas it's possible that a good radix sort implementation will improve your sorting performance, I suspect your optimization efforts would be better spent somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the test. I didn't say that the sort is the bottleneck in my program, but I'm trying to improve the performance of my code at all corners. And I'm already in the millisecond range runnning my program. So everything counts. :-)